# Installation of .Net 3.5 creates problem in ASP.Net 2.0 site

Tags: .net-3.5, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I am working on ASP.Net 2.0 website and I have a strange problem.
First let me give you details about my environment. 
I am using

```
Win XP SP2
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Version 8.0.50727.762 (SP.050727-7600)
Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0.50727 SP2
Backend is MySQL  (uses CoreLab.MySql.dll)
```

Now couple of days back I had to start working on building a website using CMS Application (Sitefinity 3.6). This requires installation of .Net Framework 3.5 SP1.

After this installation my Asp.Net 2.0 website started to behave strangely. Whenever app tries to do some data operation (e.g log in page tries to verify user in database) I get this error:

Method not found: 'Int32 System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataSet, System.String, System.Data.IDataReader, Int32, Int32)'.

Please let me know if anyone has ever face this problem. And is there any way to fix this problem because now I need to start working on new set of functionalities for ASP.Net 2.0 website.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing .net 3.5 SP1 also installs .net 2.0 SP2. There are some stuff in 2.0 that can get broken by that, including some stuff related to ngen images, [assembly loading](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/963676), JIT optimization, and [other stuff](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdateOnNETFramework35SP1AndWindowsUpdate.aspx). Not sure about the specific error you got though...

Try recompiling your 2.x app on a machine with 2.0SP2 installed if it was compiled on a machine with an earlier version of .net 2.0. And/or reinstall 3.5SP1 to ensure everything got installed properly.

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall may actually work (not a repair). Found this post about another method not found issue after .NET 3.5 SP1. The update at the top of the post and 2 comments mention uninstall/reinstall working: http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/27/NET-35-SP1-DataContractJsonSerializer-Bug.aspx

Comment: I tried to Uninstall/reinstall .NET 3.5 SP1 but no luck. Does anybody have any other solution ?

Comment: Try with enabling fusion logging. Maybe it fails to load the assembly where that function resides...   ...and fusion logging will tell you if that is the case, and hopefully also give a hint as to why...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309346(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I think the problem is now solved. It was due to .Net 2.0 SP2 which was installed with .net 3.5 SP1 (as KristoferA mentioned) so I roll backed to .Net 2.0 SP1 and after testing came to know that it worked. One more thing that I came accross during testing is that the problem was with only MySQL connection only. MS SQL Server connectivity worked fined under .Net 2.0 SP2. So as of now I have started to work on my Asp.net 2.0 web site future task. 
Thanks you guys for your suggestions.

Comment: I am still wondering that Whether it would be possible to have both sites : Asp.net 2.0 web site (which works fine with .net 2.0 SP1) and Sitefinity CMS site (that requires .Net 3.5 SP1) after installation of .Net 3.5 SP1. As of now I am just able to work on Asp.net 2.0 web site only.

Comment: I was able to figure about how to run both site. Instead of Net 3.5 SP1 I just installed Net 3.5 only (without SP1) and now both of my sites work fine.